# How to repair Chrome 75 video playback with freezes and crashes?

Tags: google-chrome

Everythings works in Chrome 74 or earlier.
However, when I install Chrome 75 on Ubuntu 18.04,
video playback does not work, Chrome 75 freezes, and after numerous clicks to get Chrome 75 to respond, Chrome 75 crashes and Ubuntu 18.04 crashes.
I cannot find any acknowledgement of these severe issues anywhere.
Google Chrome help center gives no answers nor do they respond to queries.
Nor does Ubuntu acknowledge these issues.
All answers in ask Ubuntu are many years old.
I am forced to uninstall Chrome 75, and install an earlier version.
Unfortunately, only Chrome 71 is available for Ubuntu.
Chrome 75 works on Windows 10 however. Firefox works perfectly.
bavarianph@gmail.com

Comment: Post your system specs

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Laine gnome-shell extension was causing all the problems.
when I turned the Laine extension off both google-chrome and chromium versions 75 (newest updates) worked again.
Both video and audio playback ran normally again. 
It may be an MPRIS or pulseaudio, or other gnome-shell media extension interaction with chrome or chromium 75.
this link may have further answers.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=983203#c24
see also 
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1715233

Re: Laine | Laine extension breaks video and audio playback in google chrome and chromium versions 75 and newer! (#52)
Inbox
x
Updates
x

Tommy Steimel  Unsubscribe
Tue, Jul 23, 3:10 PM (20 hours ago)
to me

Tommy Steimel commented:

Chrome 75 doesn't correctly follow the spec for the xesam:artist attribute. It's supposed to be a list of strings, but Chrome just returns a string. I have a fix out for that here: crrev.com/c/1715233. Some MPRIS clients gracefully handle that case though, so it may be worth updating Laine to not break when given just a string. Thanks!